# Clear Multiple Monitor Configuration for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

My multiple monitor configuration has got into a bad state. After unplugging my computer for a short time, I am unable to return to my precious configuration.

In Vista (and I think windows 7) I could have followed [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934552) to delete the registry subkey `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC\TMM`, however the MobilePC key does not exist in my registry.

How do I clear the multiple monitor configuration?

Comment: Windows-Key + 'P' is not what you're looking for I suppose?

Comment: Managed to resolve my own issue differently (restarting whilst having my laptop lid closed and plugged into both screens), but the question still stands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete everything under:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\
```

Then reboot.

Note that this will not *un-configure* your multiple monitors, but it will fix positioning, icons, and other weird behaviour.

Comment: Fixed my problem. I could not change settings and only use "Only use 2".

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your extra monitors on while you restart your computer seems to cause this problem.

Turn them off, or switch away from using them when restarting your computer.

For example, always switch your TV back from HDMI to TV before restarting your computer.

The solution posted by Kareem re-enables the "extend" option, but does not clear the multiple list of monitors.  At least it can get things working again.